# Which ATM in India accepts TD Debit card (Canadian)

Tags: india, canada, payment-cards

I'm going to travel to India from Canada soon. My account is with TD bank. So I would like to know which ATM or banks in India accepts debit card from TD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [TD Canada Trust Foreign Currency services](http://www.tdcanadatrust.com/products-services/banking/foreign-currency-services/taking-a-trip/trip.jsp) page on taking trips:

> If the cash you take with you runs low, look for one of close to one
>   million Automated Teller Machines worldwide displaying the PLUS
>   Network symbol. Use your Access Card to withdraw any amount up to your
>   daily limit, or take a cash advance using your TD Canada Trust Credit
>   Card. Competitive exchange rates apply.
>
> PLUS fees are waived for TD Canada Trust customers making withdrawals
>   at TD Bank ATM's from Maine to Florida and Presto! ATM's* located at
>   Publix Super Markets in Florida, Georgia, South Carolina, Tennessee
>   and Alabama.
>   * Certain states permit surcharging of international customers at independent ATMs. This surcharge will display electronically for the
>   customer to accept before completing the transaction.

They then link to an [ATM locator page for finding any ATMs worldwide](http://www.visa.com/atmlocator/index.jsp), and indeed, it finds ATMs in India.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Especially appreciate the ATM locator link.

Comment: No worries, glad to help.  Look forward to any other questions you may have on your trip!